# How to parse a text ascii protobuf string in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, protocol-buffers

I'm using protobuf in Kotlin on Android using the following gradle dependencies:

Java code generator: `com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0`

Protobuf library: `com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0`

I have the following protobuf message:

```
message Foo {
  int32 bar = 1;
  int32 bad = 2;
}
```

I have the following debug string of this message in Kotlin:

```
val debugString = """
   bar: 3
   bad: 12
"""
```

How do I parse the `debugString` into a kotlin `Foo` message object?

I've tried using `com.google.protobuf.TextFormat.merge`, however it doesn't work with the kotlin types:

```
var foo = Foo.newBuilder()
merge(debugString, foo)  // This line has an error that foo is not of right type
```

Comment: What is the _exact_ error message you get?

Comment: It doesn't compile unless I do `merge(debugString, foo as Message.Builder)`. But then at runtime I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.aaa.Proto$Foo$Builder cannot be cast to com.google.protobuf.Message$Builder`.

Comment: That sounds like you've got a version conflict (maybe with protobuf-lite?) or another class named `Foo`.

Comment: Indeed that was the error. I had a few extra lines in my gradle file that made the generated code be protobuf-lite, which makes the message inherit from MessageLite rather than Message. After deleting javalite it worked.

Comment: any one got clue for the same ?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like you've got a version conflict (maybe with protobuf-lite?) or another class named Foo.  Make sure you are generating the correct version of Foo.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by switching from protobuf lite, to the non-lite version. Unfortunately I later also needed to use Firebase which is incompatible with the non-lite version of protobuf (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2165). TextFormat does not appear to be in the lite version (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0), do you know an alternative?

Comment: @mrvladimir: Why do you need to use TextFormat?

Comment: There are two separate reasons. 1) I have some hard coded data that I would prefer to store in a proto text file rather than having a hard coded kotlin class that builds the object. 2) It our unit tests using the proto text format as input and expected output looks nice. I could forego 2. For  1) I could have some extra build step that converts the text format to the binary format but I'm not sure how to do that using gradle.

Comment: For 2), consider using [Proto Truth](https://truth.dev/protobufs.html).  Leaving out `TextFormat` is probably your only alternative -- and not a terrible thing anyway; full protos are generally more code size and trouble than they're worth on Android apps.